# Column selection mode triggering google search on Intellij

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2019.2 Community Edition, and trying to map the shortcuts just like Sublime Text 3. So far, so good. What is troubling me, though, is that I'm trying to use the Column selection mode using the combination (`Command + Shift + 8` by default) as `Command + Shift + L`.

When I try to select a text, and, then, enter the column selection mode (which is the exact situation in which I intend to use it), it simply opens Safari and searches the selected text ou Google. What troubles me is that, when I try to use the "Search on Google" shortcut, it will do so, but using Google Chrome (my default browser), therefore indicating that this is not the action being triggered.

On the other hand, when I try to enter column selection mode with the default shortcut, it will do so smoothly.

Another thing troubling me is that no keymap on conflict is indicated when using the `Command + Shift + L` shortcut, nor is it shown on the `Search Google` action. Anyone may have a clue on what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a MacOS system-wide keyboard shortcut. Look in `System Preferences | Keyboard` under the `Shortcuts` tab select `Services` in the list on the left. Now you can find `Search with Google` in the list on the right, with a default shortcut of <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. You can change or disable this shortcut to prevent the problem.

Comment: Going to look into that, but, still, that is weird. Shouldn't the same happen in Sublime, then, if it is MacOS related?

Comment: Well, anyway, it worked, so tour answer is correct. Thank you!

Also, one more question: how do you insert the keys symbols like that in your answer? I've seen it a couple of times, but I'm unable to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry, no clue why this is not a problem with Sublime. Key symbols you can create by surrounding with <kbd></kbd> tags.